# Which documentation is more comprehensive, swift.org or Apple's?

Tags: swift

I am relatively new to ios development (but I had prior programming experience) and I would like to read the full documentation of Swift, and I am not sure which one it is, There is https://docs.swift.org and there is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift
and according to swift.org

> You can use the resources on this page as documentation for the Swift language. Apple hosts additional resources for learning Swift—such as videos, sample code and playgrounds, and additional documentation—including the Swift standard library reference.

so there are a lot of overlapping documentation

so to sum it up:

1-does one of them fully include the other's documentation?

2-if not, is there a way I can read the full documentation without having to read both of them?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing apples with oranges (and equivocating on the term "comprehensive" while you're at it).

- https://docs.swift.org/ is the book about the language. You *read* it (e.g. to learn Swift). You can download it to read in the Book application (iBooks) if you like.
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift is the documentation for standard library. You *consult* it (e.g. to get a list of methods), and it is reproduced on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

swift.org is simply the open source arm of Swift.

If coding iOS/macOS apps, use the docs on Apple's site.

The docs on swift.org will not cover Apple's cocoa frameworks like UIKit.